# Printing Over the Internet

Tags: printing, http, network-printer, tcpip

I would like to know how to allow certain people, with unique user names, to be able to log in over the internet (not LAN) and be able to print their documents to my printer, which is connected to my laptop that is running Windows Server 2012. Note that this question is not like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/241377/how-do-i-remotely-print-to-a-shared-printer-over-the-internet). I have a Xerox Phaser, and it is connected to my laptop via a USB cable. I think printing over the internet is tricky, and I don't know how to do it, and I'm hoping someone here will be able to help. I think there is a fair amount involved with doing this, e.g. firewall configuration, feature/role configuration, third-party software not native to the OS, etc. To be honest, I don't know how to do this, but it would really help my small business if someone could help.

---

There is a bit of discussion here that seems a bit vague, but is what I am working off of:

http://h30565.www3.hp.com/t5/Feature-Articles/3-Ways-to-Print-Over-the-Internet/ba-p/4654

Here is another discussion about the same idea:

http://www.howtogeek.com/168769/4-easy-ways-to-remotely-print-over-the-network-or-internet/

The author writes about how "you’ll need some other tricks if you want to print to them over the Internet," so that is exactly what I'm looking for, I think.

Comment: I don't want to call Xerox, because I suspect it could be a hassle, and perhaps costly in the long run. Worse comes to worse, I'll just have to pick up a couple of books and figure out how to do it myself.

Comment: Does the printer have to be connected with an ethernet cable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked @ http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/ ? Google Cloud Print is a new technology that connects your printers to the web. Using Google Cloud Print, you can make your home and work printers available to you and anyone you choose, from the applications you use every day. Google Cloud Print works on your phone, tablet, Chromebook, PC, and any other web-connected device you want to print from.